# getting scss errors. how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, stylelint

Having these kinds of errors while running the react app.
[image]

package.json file :->

```
"lint-staged": {
"linters": {
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx}": [
    "eslint --fix",
    "git add"
  ],
  "src/**/*.scss": [
    "stylelint --fix",
    "git add"
  ]
},
"ignore": [
  "**/dist/*.min.js"
]
```

}

how can we avoid these errors? Do I need to do any changes?

Comment: Use spaces for indentation and follow the ordering. These are the settings you're using

Comment: You've configured a code style linter so you get error messages when you don't follow its rules. That's pretty much the expected behaviour. What exact solution are you looking for? Do you want to understand the rules in order to comply with them? Do you want to set different rules? Do you want to remove the linter?

Comment: If i say , I want to remove the errors. That means i need to fix them one by one ?. So, I want to remove the linter.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your tools but I suspect that removing `"stylelint --fix",` can be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour. Stylelint is flagging violations where your SCSS deviates from the rules defined in your configuration object.

As these are mostly stylistic violations, stylelint can automatically fix the majority of them for you using:

```
npx stylelint "src/**/*.scss" --fix
```

The 'Unexpected unit "em" for property "padding"' violation is not stylistic. You'll need to look at the options for the declaration-property-unit-whitelist rule in your configuration object to see what units are allowed for the padding property.